# How do I take a function out of an array if it is run?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am creating a trivia game and am running a random function with the question out of a function array but I don't want that function to get picked again. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my array:
EDIT:

```
void (*level1_sports_functionptr[3])(void) = {
    level1_sportstrivia1,
    level1_sportstrivia2,
    level1_sportstrivia3
};
void (*level1_usa_functionptr[3])(void) = {
    level1_usatrivia1,
    level1_usatrivia2,
    level1_usatrivia3
};
void (*level1_world_functionptr[3])(void) = {
    level1_worldtrivia1,
    level1_worldtrivia2,
    level1_worldtrivia3
};
```

Comment: Your question is right on topic and clear. To get good answers please [edit] the question and include the code you have already written. This gives us more context about your question and allows for better and more appropriate answers.

Comment: *Even more code* required. Where do you pick the random function? What's stopping you from setting it to NULL? Or even better, use Fisher-Yates to *shuffle* the functions then go through them in *order*

Comment: here is a link to what I am making https://repl.it/@bobby_joe/Ethan-C-game

Comment: Even more code is required **in your question**. Please [edit] it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of integers initialised with 0, 1, 2, 3, ... up to the number of elements  in your question array - in your example just 0, 1, 2.

Then apply a shuffle algorithm to this array such that the order of values is randomised.

Then select the questions by selecting an index from the shuffled array in the order they appear in that array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is in some sort of game loop. Anyway, offhand two different strategies occur to me:

First strategy: Declare a separate function pointer that simply continues your game loop. After you call a particular function, update your array with the continue function. The result will be every time it chooses an item from your array that has already been run, it triggers a redo. To the user, it will look like it always calls a new question. You'll need to keep a tally of how many questions have been called so you know when the game is over.

Second strategy: Every time you call a function, move all the elements in the array up to replace the element you just called. So, if your array is [f1,f2,f3,f4] and you call f2, you will move the elements up so your array now looks like [f1,f3,f4]. You will need to keep track of the number of functions you need to call and decrement that index each time you call a function in order to know, (1) what range to call a function from (0..3 becomes 0..2 next time) and (2) to know when you're out of questions and the game is over.

I'm sure there are other plenty of other strategies.

Comment: This should work but how do I know which function I called?

Comment: @bobbyjoe You called the function whose index you hold.

Comment: @bobbyjoe, Remember, this is an array. You access it by index: functions[3] for example would give you the fourth function in your array. However, since this is a game, you have a variable that holds your index instead. Let's say the variable is storing 3 (i.e. int index = 3;) You would then use that variable like so: functions[index] to get the fourth item in your array. So, the index variable is how you know which function you called.